# Pipeline keeps running because of Dataflow runner not closing file system writer. NotImplementedError

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I'm running a Dataflow job (Apache Beam 2.12.0) using python on the Google Cloud Platform. The pipeline is not terminating and keeps running.

The issue is the same to 
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-7266
It wasn't solved and says "open when met again". It also says that file writer is not closing.

There's only one error log:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dataflow_worker/batchworker.py", line 649, in do_work
    work_executor.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dataflow_worker/executor.py", line 178, in execute
    op.finish()
  File "dataflow_worker/native_operations.py", line 93, in dataflow_worker.native_operations.NativeWriteOperation.finish
    def finish(self):
  File "dataflow_worker/native_operations.py", line 94, in dataflow_worker.native_operations.NativeWriteOperation.finish
    with self.scoped_finish_state:
  File "dataflow_worker/native_operations.py", line 95, in dataflow_worker.native_operations.NativeWriteOperation.finish
    self.writer.__exit__(None, None, None)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dataflow_worker/nativefileio.py", line 465, in __exit__
    self.file.close()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apache_beam/io/filesystemio.py", line 202, in close
    self._uploader.finish()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apache_beam/io/gcp/gcsio.py", line 606, in finish
    raise self._upload_thread.last_error  # pylint: disable=raising-bad-type
NotImplementedError: offset: 0, whence: 0, position: 51518, last: 0
```

Comment: You could post a sanitized version of your code if you think it might be user error, but if you suspect that the error is from the bug you linked then I would recommend contacting Dataflow support as the Jira issue suggests.

Comment: Marina, Can you open a ticket with dataflow team to get it resolved as it looks like this needs access to more logs as mentioned in the jira.

Comment: Thanks, created a Cloud Dataflow issue
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/141126629